# Is this statement about continuous function and trigonometric polynomial correct?

Tags: real-analysis

If $f:[0,2\pi]\to \mathbb R$ is a continuous function such that $\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(x)T(x)=0$ for every trigonometric polynomial $T(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_k\cos kx + b_k\sin kx$, then $f=0$.

If $f$ is not continuous, then we can let $f$ be 0 except one point then the statement is false. But if $f$ is continuous, then this statement becomes true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ is continuous then for arbitrary $\epsilon$ there is a trig. pol. $T$ such that $\|f-T\|_{\infty}<\epsilon$. Then $|\int_{0}^{2\pi} f^2(x)dx|=|\int_{0}^{2\pi} f^2(x)dx-\int_{0}^{2\pi} f(x)T(x)dx|=|\int_{0}^{2\pi} f(x)(f(x)-T(x))dx|\leq $
$\epsilon\cdot \int_{0}^{2\pi} f(x)dx\leq \epsilon 2\pi\|f\|_\infty$.

Thus $\int_{0}^{2\pi} f^2(x)dx=0 \Rightarrow f^2(x)=0\Rightarrow f(x)=0$.

This is because $f^2(x)\geq 0$.

Comment: How can you infer that $f^2$=0 from the integral equals 0? Is there any quick judgement for it?

Comment: @Ethan1994, $f^2$ is positive ,continuous one the connected $[0,2\pi]$.